# change json structure of column data frame pandas with nested json

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

sorry i want to ask i want to change json structure of pandas data frame column with nested json

but after trying to search in several sources have not found a solution. Maybe someone here can help, please help!

thanks

for the code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
d = {'id': ['xxx'], 'user': ['asdam']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
result = df.to_json(orient="records")
parsed = json.loads(result)
json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
```

for the json I want it to appear something like this:
`{'id':'xxx','user':{'display_name':'asdam'}}`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a lambda function (a little strange but it works):

```
import pandas as pd
import json
d = {'id': ['xxx'], 'user': ['asdam']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['user']=df['user'].apply(lambda x: {'display_name':x}) # create a dictionary with row value
result = df.to_json(orient="records")
parsed = json.loads(result)
parsed =json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)
print(parsed)
'''
[
    {
        "id": "xxx",
        "user": {
            "display_name": "asdam"
        }
    }
]
'''
```